# Indexes for capped collectoins in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I  wonder if capped collections keep indexes for expired documents?

Removing documents from normal collection [keeps indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/delete/).

Capped collections [remove documents by timer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) and [do not allow db.collection.remove()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/)  at all.

I could not find any word in [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/) what happens with indexes for capped collections and would appreciate any help from ones who know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The only way to remove documents from a capped collection is to drop the entire collection, that will also remove the indexes themselves from the collection.

> I wonder if capped collections keep indexes for expired documents?

No. Documents that are no longer stored never remain in the index.

> Removing documents from normal collection keeps indexes.

This is a bit misleading. Removing **all** documents from a normal collection by using `db.collection.remove()` removes both the documents from the collection and also deletes those documents from the index. It does not, however, remove the indexes of the collection, i.e. once you add new documents they are being added to the respective indexes again (i.e. removing the index itself is different from deleting documents from the index).

> Capped collections remove documents by timer and do not allow `db.collection.remove()` at all.

The TTL-feature you linked has nothing to do with capped collections, in fact, the documentation says:

> *You cannot create a TTL index on a capped collection, because MongoDB cannot remove documents from a capped collection.*

A collection with a TTL index does allow db.collection.remove.

A [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/), on the other hand, has a fixed *size* (in terms of data size) and the oldest documents of the collection are automatically overwritten once the collection is full. This is not based on time, but purely on the size of the collection. Capped collections are always kept in insertion order (natural order).

Since the only way to remove documents from a capped collection is to drop the entire collection, that will also remove the indexes themselves from the collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification of difference between capped and TTL-ed collections. So what happens with indexes for documents expired by TTL?

Comment: The indexes on the collection remain. The collection is an entity of its own, so to speak. It doesn't matter whether it's currently empty or not -- after all, the TTL functionality is an index itself.